# Table without caption seems weird

Tags: tables, captions

I would like to create a table without caption but it seems not so good. I mean that there is a long line at the end of the table and it disturbs the reader.

Try:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\refstepcounter{table}\label{CDS5}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}r}

            & WAF5-H & WAF5-S & WAF4-H \\
\hline
$M{_1}$' = :87 +... + :51       & 0 & 3 & 6 \\
$M{_2}$' = :C5 +... + :E5     & 1 & 1 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

EDIT:

I use packages related with table tabular, tabularx, multirow.
The screenshot is :
[image]

Could you please help me to solve this. 
Regards,

Comment: How should somebody know that this table `Seven Of Nine` if there is no caption that prints the table number? ;-) What is the use of `\label` then?

Comment: The code you show does not make any lines. If you get lines you have a non standard definition in code you have not shown which makes it hard for anyone to comment on it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I used some tables to explain the solution steps of the problem. I do not want to copy the same explanation again and again as caption, I dont need caption

Comment: @limonik: The number is not printed with your version anyway. No one knows this is 'step' `X` of `Y` then.

Comment: the long line is not made by the code you show or any of the packages you mention. Perhaps you are using float package or a class that defines a ruled float style (which does not exist in the standard code). You should always try to post _complete_ documents that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it only in a `center` environment

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}r}
            & WAF5-H & WAF5-S & WAF4-H \\\hline
$M{_1}$' = :87 +... + :51       & 0 & 3 & 6 \\
$M{_2}$' = :C5 +... + :E5     & 1 & 1 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```